# O mapa VFA é impresso sem dados

Tags: crystal-reports

Fiz alterações no mapa utilizado para imprimir VFA, adicionando a tabela `Movimentos` para ver a conta CBL do fornecedor no cabeçalhos. E quando o registo de uma VFA não origina um registo na tabela `Movimentos` da base de dados o mapa é impresso sem dados.

Fiz a ligação das tabelas `Movimentos` e `CabecCompras` através dos campos (NumDoc, TipoDoc, Série e Entidade).

Conta no cabeçalho do documento é impressa `({Movimentos.Conta})`.

Podem ajudar-me a perceber o que estou fazendo para estar a ter esse resultado sff? Obrigado.

Comment: @acmiloMoz Esta é uma questão a ser colocada no ambito do forum privado https://developers.primaverabss.com/questions/categories/v10/ por não se tratar de uma questão de programação, logo fora deste ambito.

Se mesmo assim não existir conseguires resposta deves abrir um incidente junto da PRIMAVERA.

Comment: Obrigado Sereno! Vou já colocar no forum que referiu.

Comment: Achei que fiz alterações de uma forma inadequada. pois quando não uso o valor da conta no cabeçalho tudo funciona bem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já consegui solução para o desafio, ao adicionar a tabela de Movimentos tive que indicar quais os tipos de ligação para os campos (Documento, TipoDoc, Entidade e Série) com as opções Right Outer join e Not Inforced marcadas, para quando a tabela Movimentos não tiver o registo da VFA deve ser ignorada. [image: Ilustração]